# Space getting added between string and row

Tags: python, csv, space

New to Python, obvious from the code I hacked together from various examples.

The problem I'm running into is the output of print is inserting space so I'm getting "edit tcp_ 8080" instead of "edit tcp_8080"

The sample.csv would be a column of various ports/numbers.

How do I remove the space its putting between the string and the row.

Thanks for the time.

```
 import csv

f = open('sample1.csv', 'r')
e = "edit tcp_"
s = "set tcp-portrange "
n = "next"
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

#outStr = ''
for row in csv_f:  #for always end in a colon
    print e,row[0]
    print s,row[0]
    print n
#t = open('output.txt','w')
#t.write(outStr)
#t.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: You want `print e + str(row[0])`. If you supply multiple elements to `print` separated by a comma, a space will be inserted between them. Instead you want to append the strings.

Comment: what's the str?
Also if row[1] includes multiple words. How can I get the output to wrap in quotes. example "custom port for web".   -I need that wrapped in " in the output.

Comment: `str` ensures that `row[0]` is a string (so it can be successfully combined with another string). Also could do `print '"{0}{1}"'.format(e, row[0])`

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. 
How can I clean this up
I"m trying to wrap row 2 in quotes. And how would I skip that field if it didn't have an entry?
`qq = '"'`
`print com + qq + str(row[2])+qq`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
import csv

f = open('sample1.csv', 'r')
e = "edit tcp_"
s = "set tcp-portrange "
n = "next"
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

#outStr = ''
for row in csv_f:  #for always end in a colon
    print '{0}{1}'.format(e,row[0])
    print '{0}{1}'.format(s,row[0])
    print n
#t = open('output.txt','w')
#t.write(outStr)
#t.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `print e+row[0]`.

That works as long as both are strings, otherwise you need to either cast to string with `str` or use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

```
string_with_space = 'string with space'
with_no_space = ''.join(string_with_space.splt(' '))
print with_no_space
```